# Least Upper Bound Proof

Tags: calculus

I am looking for a proof for this:

> If $S=(a,b)=\{x\in\mathbb R\, :\, a < x < b\}$, then the least upper bound of $ S$ is $b$

My professor was fumbling through an explanation and I got lost.

Comment: I just fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Claim: $b$ is an upper bound. Indeed, for every $x \in S$, we have $x < b \leq b$.

Claim: $b$ is the least upper bound. Indeed, for contradiction let $c$ be a smaller upper bound. Then $\color{red}{a < c} < b$, so $a < c < \frac{b+c}{2} < b$; but that means $\frac{b+c}{2} \in S$ which contradicts that $c$ is an upper bound.

(You should prove that any upper bound must be greater than $a$, to justify the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ step.)

Comment: Let's say c' =b+c/2, then wouldn't c' be the new LUB?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "new LUB". What do you mean by that?

Comment: Can you clarify something and then it probably will make sense; Since this concept is used to define the real number line, is the point that there is no number that exists between the GLB and the LUB?

Comment: The GLB of $(a, b)$ is $a$. The LUB of $(a, b)$ is $b$. The number $\frac{a+b}{2}$ lies strictly between them.

Comment: I am obviously struggling with this concept!  Where do the GLB and LUB meet?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$, if and only if the bounded set you are considering is a one-point set. Indeed, if $a, b \in I$ with $a < b$, then the GLB is less than or equal to $a$ and the LUB is greater than or equal to $b$, so they can't be the same.

Comment: I appreciate your patience.